# Using a bool across multiple pages in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, boolean

I've been attempting to pass a bool value across multiple pages. I've built a program that has  a login page and four different pages upon successful login. I have an admin and an employee. My problem is that the admin and employee have to have different views -- that is, when the admin is logged in, certain buttons throughout the various pages are visible to him, whereas when the employee is logged in, they are not.

Thus, the problem: How to pass a bool across multiple pages? The bool sets itself upon a login. I was originally passing around the bool through each page, but stack overflow occurs.

- My other ideas were to bind the visibility of the buttons to the outcome of the bool, but I've yet to be successful.
- Other idea was to make a class for the bool and reference the getters/setters there each time a page opens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to share a plain normal session in your application.

Just create a model for it

```
public class SessionModel
{
    public bool IsAdmin { get; private set; }

    public SessionModel(bool isAdmin)
    {
        IsAdmin = isAdmin;
    }
}
```

and make this accessible to your Views via MVVM, then in your view check the values of your ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Your user class (model) should have the permission info which you should convert to bool/visibility/xyz things to render UI.